# Strcmp and getchar

Tags: c, strcmp, getchar

I have written a small c program that displays text entered and if text entered is "show version", it displays the version.
Here is the sample code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main(){
int i;
char j = (char) i;
while(i != '#'){
i = getchar();
if(strcmp(&j, "show version")) printf("v1");
else putchar(i);
}}
```

It prints v1 for every char+1.
Any suggestions.

Comment: The value of `j` is unknown... it does not get modified when you set `i` because you don't assign `i` to `j` after changing `i`.  Also, `strcmp()` expects null terminated strings... a pointer to a single (probably) non-null `char` is not enough -- it will continue reading past that single char until it finds a null character or has already determined the strings don't match.  In other words, you've got a lot of undefined behaviour and appear to have some misunderstandings about how the language works.  (and those aren't the only problems with the code)

Answer (score 0):

Read the [man pages for strcmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).

The return value of `strcmp` is `0` *if* both strings are equal, which in a C condition is considered equivalent to *false*.

Change your if..statement to the following:

```
if(strcmp(&j, "show version") == 0) printf("v1");
```

NOTE: In order for your code to parse a string, you will need to append each character you read onto a string.

```
#define LINE_SIZE 512

int main(){
    char *line = malloc(LINE_SIZE);
    while(fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, stdin)) {
        if(strncmp(line, "show version", strlen(line) - 1) == 0) {
            printf("v1\n");
        } else {
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The reason why I used `strncmp` (rather than `strcmp`) and `strlen(line) - 1` is because `fgets` also captures the ENTER key / newline character when entered. This is just an example - do not forget to free your memory!

Comment: What about the fact that (in the original code) `&j` doesn't even refer to a null terminated string, and that `j`'s value was assigned from an uninitialised variable?  Or that `j` isn't modified in the loop anyway (only `i` is)?